# Unable to sum raster files in R using raster package

Tags: r, raster-calculator, rgdal

I am trying to sum all of my raster files (over 500) from a single folder in R, using the `raster` package, but am encountering an error message I cannot figure out how to solve. I am trying to use to use this package to use the raster calculator to sum these files.

I have a folder of raster images (.tif). I then run the following code in R.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

allrasters <- stack(list.files('C:/Users/MyName/Path/to/My/Data/Folder', full.names=T)

raster_sum <- calc(allrasters, fun=sum,na.rm=T, ,filename='C:/Users/MyName/Path/to/Outputs/Folder/Raster_Sum_Output.tif')
```

which yields the following error message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘calc’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "numeric"’
```

What might be the cause for this, and how can I fix this problem so that I can get my intended output raster which is the sum of all the raster files in my folder? have not been able to find online how I might address this issue, since the the "RasterStack" and "numeric" components are too specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got a *numeric* object called `sum`?

```
> sum=99
> raster_sum <- calc(allrasters, fun=sum,na.rm=TRUE)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘calc’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "numeric"’
```

The error is saying you are calling `calc` with a RasterLayer and a numeric argument, so the second argument must be numeric, and not a function. Remove any `sum` numeric object, or do `base::sum`:

```
> raster_sum <- calc(allrasters, base::sum, na.rm=TRUE)
>
```

(Oh and *always* spell `TRUE` out because that can break stuff too...)

Comment: Thank you, this is working so far now, your suggestion of replacing `fun=sum` with `base::sum` got the code to run. Though the code has been running for a good 45 minutes now, and I'm wondering if these seems reasonable for summing over 500 raster files, or if I should expect this to run much quicker.

Comment: All depends on the number of pixels. Try with a few subsets, time it, estimate the time for the whole set...

Comment: Good suggestion, I just checked the raster information in QGIS, and each raster file has Pixel Size: 100,-100, which did not seem like that much to me at first, but maybe I was wrong and created rasters with too high a resolution.

Comment: "Pixel size" isn't the issue, pixel *count* is. Read one stack into R and check the summary.

Comment: I tried a subset folder with just 4 of the raster files, and the code ran and completed in just a few seconds, and looking out the output raster file in QGIS, it looks just as I would intend. Though the message: `Warning in .gd_SetProject(object, ...) : NOT UPDATED FOR PROJ >= 6` was produced, and I am not sure if this is an issue. I am not sure about the summary, but I simply ran `allrasters` and was returned: `dimensions : 6418, 7821, 50195178, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)`, but I don't think that says anything about the pixel count. Maybe the pixel count is too high then? How do I check?

Comment: It works with 4, so try 8, then 16, then 32, then 64. Time it each time, and plot a graph, estimate the time for 500. Your stack has 50195178 pixels (cells) in 4 layers of 6418x7821.